# Kotlin, covert timer activity into a fragment, encountering some errors - Type mismatch. Required: Context! Found: fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a timer activity. That works great. Now i want to convert that timer into a fragment so I can use it inside a tabLayout.

Now I get some errors inside my PrefUtilStartTimerFrag. With all the "context" I get the error:
Type mismatch.
Required:
Context!
Found:
TabStartTimerFragment

First, this is my Timer fragment Kotlin file:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.fotf.klimaatambitiegame.util.PrefUtilStartTimerFrag
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_tab_start_timer.*

class TabStartTimerFragment : Fragment() {

    enum class TimerState {
        Stopped, Paused, Running
    }

    private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
    private var timerLengthSeconds: Int = 30
    private var timerState = TimerState.Stopped
    private var secondsRemaining = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_start_timer, container, false)
    }
       // val fab_start = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_startfrag)
       // val fab_pause = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_pausefrag)
       // val fab_stop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_stopfrag)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        fab_startfrag.setOnClickListener {
            startTimer()
            timerState = TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running
            updateButtons()
        }

        fab_pausefrag.setOnClickListener {
            timer.cancel()
            timerState = TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Paused
            updateButtons()
        }

        fab_stopfrag.setOnClickListener {
            timer.cancel()
            onTimerFinished()
            updateButtons()
        }


    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        initTimer()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        if (timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running) {
            timer.cancel()
        } else if (timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Paused) {

        }
        PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.setPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(timerLengthSeconds, this)
        PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining, this)
        PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.setTimerState(timerState, this)


    }

    fun initTimer() {
        timerState = PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.getTimerState(this)

        if (timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Stopped)
            setNewTimerLength()
        else
            setPreviousTimerLength()

        secondsRemaining = if (timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running || timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Paused)
            PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.getSecondsRemaining(this).toInt()
        else
            timerLengthSeconds

        if (timerState == TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running)
            startTimer()
        updateButtons()
        updateCountdownUI()
    }

    private fun onTimerFinished() {
        //var progress_countdown = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_countdown)
        timerState = TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Stopped
        setNewTimerLength()

        progress_countdown.progress = 0
        PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.setSecondsRemaining(timerLengthSeconds, this)
        secondsRemaining = timerLengthSeconds

        updateButtons()
        updateCountdownUI()
    }

    private fun startTimer() {
        var mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.elephant)
        timerState = TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running
        timer = object : CountDownTimer((secondsRemaining * 1000).toLong(), 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {

                onTimerFinished()
                mp.start()
            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                secondsRemaining = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toInt()
                updateCountdownUI()
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun setNewTimerLength() {
        //var progress_countdown = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_countdown)
        var lengthInMinutes = PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.getTimerLength(this)
        timerLengthSeconds = ((lengthInMinutes * 60L).toInt())
        progress_countdown.max = timerLengthSeconds.toInt()
    }

    private fun setPreviousTimerLength() {
        //var progress_countdown = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_countdown)
        timerLengthSeconds = PrefUtilStartTimerFrag.getPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(this).toInt()
        progress_countdown.max = timerLengthSeconds.toInt()
    }

    private fun updateCountdownUI() {
        //var progress_countdown = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_countdown)
       // val textView_Countdown = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timer_textview)
        val minutesUntilFinished = secondsRemaining / 60
        val secondsInMinutesUntilFinished = secondsRemaining - minutesUntilFinished * 60
        val secondsStr = secondsInMinutesUntilFinished.toString()
        timer_textviewfrag.text = "$minutesUntilFinished:${
            if (secondsStr.length == 2) secondsStr
            else "0" + secondsStr}"
        progress_countdown.progress = (timerLengthSeconds - secondsRemaining).toInt()
    }

    private fun updateButtons() {
        //val fab_start = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_start)
        //val fab_pause = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_pause)
        //val fab_stop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fab_stop)
        when (timerState) {
            TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Running -> {
                fab_startfrag.isEnabled = false
                fab_pausefrag.isEnabled = true
                fab_stopfrag.isEnabled = true
            }

            TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Stopped -> {
                fab_startfrag.isEnabled = true
                fab_pausefrag.isEnabled = false
                fab_stopfrag.isEnabled = false
            }

            TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.Paused -> {
                fab_startfrag.isEnabled = true
                fab_pausefrag.isEnabled = false
                fab_stopfrag.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, this is my PrefUtilStartTimerFrag file:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.fotf.klimaatambitiegame.StadKaartActivity
import com.fotf.klimaatambitiegame.TabStartTimerFragment

class PrefUtilStartTimerFrag {
    companion object {
        fun getTimerLength(context: TabStartTimerFragment): Double {
            //placeholder
            return 0.5
        }

        //private var defValue: Long
        private const val PREVIOUS_TIMER_LENGTH_SECONDS_ID = "com.resoconder.timer.previous_timer_length"

        fun getPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(context: TabStartTimerFragment): Long {
            val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            return preferences.getLong(PREVIOUS_TIMER_LENGTH_SECONDS_ID, 0)
        }

        fun setPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(seconds: Int, context: TabStartTimerFragment) {
            val editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit() //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            editor.putLong(PREVIOUS_TIMER_LENGTH_SECONDS_ID, seconds.toLong())
            editor.apply()
        }

        private const val TIMER_STATE_ID = "com.resocoder.timer.timer_state"

        fun getTimerState(context: TabStartTimerFragment): TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState {
            val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            val ordinal = preferences.getInt(TIMER_STATE_ID, 0)
            return TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState.values()[ordinal]
        }

        fun setTimerState(state: TabStartTimerFragment.TimerState, context: TabStartTimerFragment) {
            val editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit() //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            val ordinal = state.ordinal
            editor.putInt(TIMER_STATE_ID, ordinal)
            editor.apply()
        }

        private const val SECONDS_REMAINING_ID = "com.resoconder.timer.previous_timer_length"

        fun getSecondsRemaining(context: TabStartTimerFragment): Long {
            val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            return preferences.getLong(SECONDS_REMAINING_ID, 0)
        }

        fun setSecondsRemaining(seconds: Int, context: TabStartTimerFragment) {
            val editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit() //<- Error Type mismatch. Required: Context!
            editor.putLong(SECONDS_REMAINING_ID, seconds.toLong())
            editor.apply()
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can I fix these errors?

Comment: Please add error logs along with question.

Comment: fragment is not a context, but the activity is; so replace `context` with `requireContext()` or `getContext()`